# How to make the Menu key on my keyboard work in Mathematica

Tags: keyboard, windows

My Menu key works in Windows Explorer, Internet Explorer, many apps, but does not work in *Mathematica's* notebook.

The function is like that of Right-Click with the mouse.

*Function expected*: Select some text in the cell, and tap the menu-key comes out the menu.

In my keyboard, it's between the Right-ALT-Key and the Right-Ctrl-key.

If this is not possible, how to make one key, or combination of some Control Keys to do the same thing, ie use the keyboard to substitute the right-click of mouse?

Answer (score 1):

**This technically is a wrong answer because it doesn't bring up the context menu for the selected cell, but where the cursor is located, but I am leaving it up fore now bcause I believe the final answer will involve using AutoHotKey in some way because Mathematica appears to fail to detect the MenuKey.**

I am not sure why Mathematica doesn't allow you to use the context menu key. maybe somebody else can shed light onto the internal of mathematica.

As a work around you can download [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and put this in a file and run it.

```
AppsKey::RButton
```

Technically this is slightly different because the context menu will appear in the cursor location instead of in the top left that most applications display.

Comment: oh,thanks, Do you mean the context menu key works ok in Your Mathematica Notebook?

Comment: @HyperGroups No it doesn't work.  Download Autohotkey and run the text file above through autohotkey to get it to work.